# Winforms Drag and Drop not working any more

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop

I created a new project and put a new form to allow Drag & Drop of a file.
In the designer, there is set: `Me.AllowDrop = True`
But it seems that is is not working.
Here is the code for the form:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class frmDragNDropTesting
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Public Sub New()
        ' Set up the form
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Register event handlers
        'AddHandler Me.DragEnter, AddressOf MainForm_DragEnter
        'AddHandler Me.DragDrop, AddressOf MainForm_DragDrop
    End Sub

    ' Event handler for when a file is dragged over the form
    Private Sub MainForm_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles MyBase.DragEnter
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link

        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End If
    End Sub

    ' Event handler for when a file is dropped onto the form
    Private Sub MainForm_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles MyBase.DragDrop
        MessageBox.Show("Something was dropped!")
        Dim files As String() = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

        If files.Length > 0 Then
            Dim file As String = files(0)
            Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower()

            ' Process the dropped file
            ' Add your code here to handle the dropped file as needed
            MessageBox.Show("Dropped file path: " & file)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I am using VS 2022 in Windows 11. When I run the application and try to drag a file onto the form, a red 'no-entry' icon appears and DragEnter and DragDrop events do not fire.

Any ideas why it is not working, please?

Comment: Ensure you do not have VS running in administrator mode.  D+D into an elevated app is forbidden.

Comment: Hi Hans
Yes the VS is running as Administrator. But when I double click on the exe generated (as Debug Mode) it works fine!!!

Comment: It seems like the VS is preventing the D&D ...

Comment: Technically it is not VS that prevents it, the debugger merely launches your app with the same account as used in VS.  So if VS was elevated then your app will be as well.  No option to run at normal UAC level, just don't run VS elevated to fix.

Comment: So  @HansPassant, if you run an exe as Administrator, it will not run??

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem thanks to Hans Passant.
VS was running in elevated mode and it seems that Drag & Drop will not work in elevated mode.

Comment: It will work, you just can't drag from a non-elevated app into an elevated app.  That's a privilege inversion.  From one elevated app into another is fine.  Google "shatter attack" to learn more about the risks.